# Convert a MySQL timestamp to actual datetime format ina MySQL query

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have following query and data saved in a MySQL database with a timestamp column. I have to display the timestamp as the actual data and time format like 1333007294 it should be displayed as `03-MAR-2012 12:48:14` PM. I have tried to use MySQL using from_unixtime but it displays the datetime like this `3/29/2012 12:00:00 am`. I need to get the format like `03-MAR-2012 12:48:14 PM` here is my query.

```
SELECT DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `timestamp` ) ) AS timestamp
from vlasteventwdevice
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: Please leave a comment when you downvote

Comment: What do u mean by sir I dont understand ur suggestion

Comment: @matino's comment was not for you, user1220667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`, '%d-%b-%Y %r')
```

You can make the result upper case later in your application code

Comment: This results the Empty Column